# BPMN 2.0, kogito, triggering signal or message from another process

Tags: jbpm, bpmn, kogito

I am using kogito (kogito-quarkus(1.26.0)) with quarkus(2.9.2), maven (4.0.0) and java 11.

I want to communicate with an ongoing process, probably waiting for an event (message). See the image below.
[image: process one]

Once I start this process, it waits on the event conditional for a message, at least what I understood.

And what I want to do is, triggering this particular process from another process. In order to achieve it, I made another process sends message to the particular topic that previous process listens to. See the image blow.

[image]

This is not a working example, I am just trying to preview what I want to do.

The problem here is, the process two does not know about the process one. How can I configure the system so that process two knows the exact process to trigger this message.

Kogito have a similar example but in their example, process one first throws a message that triggers process two, and communication with two processes establishes. See the example here: [Kogito Travel Agency](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/stable/kogito-quarkus-examples/kogito-travel-agency/extended)

I do not know if its possible, I am kind of new in BPMN. Any help and comments appreciated.

I have tried establishing the same system with project scoped signals, unfortunately it did not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the description of this JIRA https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-6287
This is not fully working on Kogito yet, because it needs https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KOGITO-8137
But the point is the correlation covers the scenario in which second process does not have the id of the first one.